# Why can't Spring find resource files?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, netbeans

I'm running NetBeans with Spring framework. The web page shows up but it is not formated. It doesn't find the css and js files.  What am I doing wrong?

**NetBeans**

[image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>MedAI - Medical Artifical Intelligence</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>        
    <link href="resources/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="resources/css/medai.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div>
            <h1>MedAI</h1>
            <span class=version>V 1.0.0</span>            
    </div>

    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="<c:url value='/jsp/homeTab' />">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="<c:url value='/jsp/geneNetworkTab' />">Gene Network</a></li>
            <li><a href="<c:url value='/jsp/diseaseNetworkTab' />">Disease Network</a></li>
    </ul>  
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tabs')
                .tabs()
                //.addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
            });    
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

**redirect.jsp**

```
<%--
Views should be stored under the WEB-INF folder so that
they are not accessible except through controller process.

This JSP is here to provide a redirect to the dispatcher
servlet but should be the only JSP outside of WEB-INF.
--%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %>
```

Comment: Try to specify `src="../resources/js/jquery.js"` or `src="WEB-INF/resources/js/jquery.js"` because your `.jsp` is inside `jsp` folder, it is not same level with `resources` folde

Comment: adding ../ in front of resources did not change anything.  Same "404 not found" error.

Comment: adding WEB-INF/ in front of resources did not change anything either.  Same error.

Comment: Opps, I have wrong, because your `resources` folder is not inside the `WEB-INF`. Please put your `resources` folder inside the `WEB-INF` so that the server can find your resource. (do not change code like I mention above)

Comment: Ok, I put code back the way it was and moved resource folder inside WEB-INF but it is still not finding resources.

Comment: Last change mate! Keep the resource inside WEB-INF and use the path I have mention above. If this does not work then it's weird.

Comment: Ok, tried that but still not finding it.  Shameful that documentation is so bad.  Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out by starting over from scratch.  The only thing wrong was this line should not have been there in web.xml

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should enable [default servlet handler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

</beans>
```

**OR** using [resources mapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) instead, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
</beans>
```

**OR** register a default servlet request handler instead, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
        <property name="defaultHandler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**IF** you still don't know how to do, I suggest you read the whole [Spring WebMvc Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-web.html) first.

Comment: Where does it go?  Inside the beans tag or outside?

Comment: @user3217883 Hi, I add the link of how to configure a spring MVC project. you can click and see it.

Comment: The link doesn't say where to put it either.  I put it outside the beans tag.  Now the page doesn't show up at all and I see error "GET 
http://localhost:8080/MedAI/index.htm [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: @user3217883 where is the default-servlet-handler you put in? I already said put it in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and make ture you the mvc schema  was added.

Comment: @user3217883 please see [how to config spring WebMVC project](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable)  first.

Comment: Sorry I just don't understand it.  It's all gobbledy gook.  Can anybody explain in simple english?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i'd solved it creating another servlet for static content like this:

add this lines to your web.xml after your dispatcher like this:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.eproducts.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>     
    </servlet-mapping>
```

declare the class handler:

```
package com.eproducts.servlets;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class DefaultServlet extends HttpServlet
{   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, and GlassFish 
    private static final String COMMON_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "default";

    // Resin 
    private static final String RESIN_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "resin-file";

    // WebLogic 
    private static final String WEBLOGIC_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "FileServlet";

    // WebSphere 
    private static final String WEBSPHERE_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "SimpleFileServlet";


    public String scanDefaultServlet(){
        if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(COMMON_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null) {
            return COMMON_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
        } else if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(RESIN_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null) {
            return RESIN_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
        } else if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(WEBLOGIC_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null){
            return WEBLOGIC_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
        } else if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(WEBSPHERE_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null){
            return WEBSPHERE_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot determine what Server you currently use");
        }       
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(this.scanDefaultServlet());
        HttpServletRequest wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
                public String getServletPath() {return "";}
        };
        rd.forward(wrapped, resp);
    }
}
```

after do that you can add your resources like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/public/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>
```

[EDIT]:

add the following library before your resources to make working the tag `<c:url/>`

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your index.jsp, change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>        
    <link href="resources/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="resources/css/medai.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery.js" />" ></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery-ui.js" />" ></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.js" />" ></script>        
    <link href="<c:url value="resources/css/jquery-ui.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<c:url value="resources/css/medai.css" />" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

Then in your dispatcher-servlet.xml, add

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```